# C++ linked list has junk nodes appearing in it

Tags: c++, memory-management, linked-list

When implementing a call stack trace for tracking allocation in my overridden new function, I am using ::malloc to create an untracked call stack object that is then put into a linked list. When my harness finishes new-ing off all of the test cases, the list is sound. However, when i go to report the list (print to console) there are now values that should not be there and are causing it to crash. Below is the simplified version (I apologize that even simplified it is still a lot of code), I am hoping someone can make since of this:

### Macros

```
#define convertToKiB(size) size * 1024UL
#define convertToMiB(size) size * (1024UL * 1024UL)
#define convertToGiB(size) size * (1024UL * 1024UL * 1024UL)
#define convertToReadableBytes(size) ((uint32_t)size > convertToKiB(2) && (uint32_t)size < convertToMiB(2)) ? (float)size / (float)convertToKiB(1) : ((uint32_t)size > convertToMiB(2) && (uint32_t)size < convertToGiB(2)) ? (float)size / (float)convertToMiB(1) : ((uint32_t)size > convertToGiB(2)) ? (float)size / (float)convertToMiB(1) : (float)size
#define convertToReadableBytesString(size) ((uint32_t)size > convertToKiB(2) && (uint32_t)size < convertToMiB(2)) ? "KiB" : ((uint32_t)size > convertToMiB(2) && (uint32_t)size < convertToGiB(2)) ? "MiB" : ((uint32_t)size > convertToGiB(2)) ? "GiB" : "B"
```

### Globals

```
const uint8_t MAX_FRAMES_PER_CALLSTACK = 128;
const uint16_t MAX_SYMBOL_NAME_LENGTH = 128;
const uint32_t MAX_FILENAME_LENGTH = 1024;
const uint16_t MAX_DEPTH = 128;

typedef BOOL(__stdcall *sym_initialize_t)(IN HANDLE hProcess, IN PSTR UserSearchPath, IN BOOL fInvadeProcess);
typedef BOOL(__stdcall *sym_cleanup_t)(IN HANDLE hProcess);
typedef BOOL(__stdcall *sym_from_addr_t)(IN HANDLE hProcess, IN DWORD64 Address, OUT PDWORD64 Displacement, OUT PSYMBOL_INFO Symbol);
typedef BOOL(__stdcall *sym_get_line_t)(IN HANDLE hProcess, IN DWORD64 dwAddr, OUT PDWORD pdwDisplacement, OUT PIMAGEHLP_LINE64 Symbol);

static HMODULE g_debug_help;
static HANDLE g_process;
static SYMBOL_INFO* g_symbol;

static sym_initialize_t g_sym_initialize;
static sym_cleanup_t g_sym_cleanup;
static sym_from_addr_t g_sym_from_addr;
static sym_get_line_t g_sym_get_line_from_addr_64;

static int g_callstack_count = 0;
static callstack_list* g_callstack_root = nullptr;
```

### CallStack Object

```
struct callstack_line_t
{
    char file_name[128];
    char function_name[256];
    uint32_t line;
    uint32_t offset;
};

class CallStack
{
public:
    CallStack();

    uint32_t m_hash;
    uint8_t m_frame_count;
    void* m_frames[MAX_FRAMES_PER_CALLSTACK];
};

CallStack::CallStack()
    : m_hash(0)
    , m_frame_count(0) {}

bool CallstackSystemInit()
{
    // Load the dll, similar to OpenGL function fecthing.
    // This is where these functions will come from.
    g_debug_help = LoadLibraryA("dbghelp.dll");
    if (g_debug_help == nullptr) {
        return false;
    }

    // Get pointers to the functions we want from the loded library.
    g_sym_initialize = (sym_initialize_t)GetProcAddress(g_debug_help, "SymInitialize");
    g_sym_cleanup = (sym_cleanup_t)GetProcAddress(g_debug_help, "SymCleanup");
    g_sym_from_addr = (sym_from_addr_t)GetProcAddress(g_debug_help, "SymFromAddr");
    g_sym_get_line_from_addr_64 = (sym_get_line_t)GetProcAddress(g_debug_help, "SymGetLineFromAddr64");

    // Initialize the system using the current process [see MSDN for details]
    g_process = ::GetCurrentProcess();
    g_sym_initialize(g_process, NULL, TRUE);

    // Preallocate some memory for loading symbol information. 
    g_symbol = (SYMBOL_INFO *) ::malloc(sizeof(SYMBOL_INFO) + (MAX_FILENAME_LENGTH * sizeof(char)));
    g_symbol->MaxNameLen = MAX_FILENAME_LENGTH;
    g_symbol->SizeOfStruct = sizeof(SYMBOL_INFO);

    return true;
}

void CallstackSystemDeinit()
{
    // cleanup after ourselves
    ::free(g_symbol);
    g_symbol = nullptr;

    g_sym_cleanup(g_process);

    FreeLibrary(g_debug_help);
    g_debug_help = NULL;
}

// Can not be static - called when
// the callstack is freed.
void DestroyCallstack(CallStack *ptr)
{
    ::free(ptr);
}

CallStack* CreateCallstack(uint8_t skip_frames)
{
    // Capture the callstack frames - uses a windows call
    void *stack[MAX_DEPTH];
    DWORD hash;

    // skip_frames:  number of frames to skip [starting at the top - so don't return the frames for "CreateCallstack" (+1), plus "skip_frame_" layers.
    // max_frames to return
    // memory to put this information into.
    // out pointer to back trace hash.
    uint32_t frames = CaptureStackBackTrace(1 + skip_frames, MAX_DEPTH, stack, &hash);

    // create the callstack using an untracked allocation
    CallStack *cs = (CallStack*) ::malloc(sizeof(CallStack));

    // force call the constructor (new in-place)
    cs = new (cs) CallStack();

    // copy the frames to our callstack object
    unsigned int frame_count = min(MAX_FRAMES_PER_CALLSTACK, frames);
    cs->m_frame_count = frame_count;
    ::memcpy(cs->m_frames, stack, sizeof(void*) * frame_count);

    cs->m_hash = hash;

    return cs;
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Fills lines with human readable data for the given callstack
// Fills from top to bottom (top being most recently called, with each next one being the calling function of the previous)
//
// Additional features you can add;
// [ ] If a file exists in yoru src directory, clip the filename
// [ ] Be able to specify a list of function names which will cause this trace to stop.
uint16_t CallstackGetLines(callstack_line_t *line_buffer, const uint16_t max_lines, CallStack *cs)
{
    IMAGEHLP_LINE64 line_info;
    DWORD line_offset = 0; // Displacement from the beginning of the line 
    line_info.SizeOfStruct = sizeof(IMAGEHLP_LINE64);

    unsigned int count = min(max_lines, cs->m_frame_count);
    unsigned int idx = 0;

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        callstack_line_t *line = &(line_buffer[idx]);
        DWORD64 ptr = (DWORD64)(cs->m_frames[i]);
        if (FALSE == g_sym_from_addr(g_process, ptr, 0, g_symbol)) {
            continue;
        }

        strcpy_s(line->function_name, 256, g_symbol->Name);

        BOOL bRet = g_sym_get_line_from_addr_64(
            GetCurrentProcess(), // Process handle of the current process 
            ptr,                 // Address 
            &line_offset,        // Displacement will be stored here by the function 
            &line_info);         // File name / line information will be stored here 

        if (bRet)
        {
            line->line = line_info.LineNumber;
            strcpy_s(line->file_name, 128, line_info.FileName);
            line->offset = line_offset;
        }
        else {
            // no information
            line->line = 0;
            line->offset = 0;
            strcpy_s(line->file_name, 128, "N/A");
        }

        ++idx;
    }

    return idx;
}
```

### Operators

```
// Treat as Linked List Node
struct callstack_list
{
    CallStack* current_stack = nullptr;
    uint16_t total_allocation = 0;
    callstack_list* next = nullptr;
};

struct allocation_meta
{
    uint16_t size;
    callstack_list callstack_node;
};

void* operator new(const size_t size)
{
    uint16_t alloc_size = (uint16_t)size + (uint16_t)sizeof(allocation_meta);
    allocation_meta *ptr = (allocation_meta*)::malloc((size_t)alloc_size);
    ptr->size = (uint16_t)size;

    ptr->callstack_node.current_stack = CreateCallstack(0);
    ptr->callstack_node.total_allocation = (uint16_t)size;
    ptr->callstack_node.next = nullptr;

    bool run = true;
    callstack_list* currentNode = nullptr;
    while (g_callstack_root != nullptr && run)
    {
        if (currentNode == nullptr)
        {
            currentNode = g_callstack_root;
        }

        if (currentNode->next != nullptr)
        {
            currentNode = currentNode->next;
        }
        else
        {
            currentNode->next = &ptr->callstack_node;
            run = false;
        }

    }

    if (g_callstack_root == nullptr)
    {
        g_callstack_root = &ptr->callstack_node;
    }

    return ptr + 1;
}

void operator delete(void* ptr)
{
    if (nullptr == ptr)
        return;

    allocation_meta *data = (allocation_meta*)ptr;
    data--;

    if (data->callstack_node.current_stack != nullptr)
        DestroyCallstack(data->callstack_node.current_stack);

    bool run = true;
    callstack_list* currentNode = nullptr;
    while (g_callstack_root != nullptr && run && &data->callstack_node != NULL)
    {
        if (currentNode == nullptr && g_callstack_root != &data->callstack_node)
        {
            currentNode = g_callstack_root;
        }
        else
        {
            g_callstack_root = nullptr;
            run = false;
            continue;
        }

        if (currentNode->next != nullptr && currentNode->next != &data->callstack_node)
        {
            currentNode = currentNode->next;
        }
        else
        {
            currentNode->next = nullptr;
            run = false;
        }
    }

    ::free(data);
}
```

### Test Harness

```
void ReportVerboseCallStacks(const char* start_time_str = "", const char* end_time_str = "")
{
    callstack_list* currentNode = g_callstack_root;

    unsigned int totalSimiliarAllocs = 0;
    uint32_t totalSimiliarSize = 0;

    while (currentNode != nullptr)
    {
        callstack_list* nextNode = currentNode->next;

        uint32_t& currentHash = currentNode->current_stack->m_hash;
        uint32_t nextHash;
        if (nextNode == nullptr)
            nextHash = currentHash + 1;
        else
            nextHash = nextNode->current_stack->m_hash;

        if (nextHash == currentHash)
        {
            totalSimiliarSize += currentNode->total_allocation;
            totalSimiliarAllocs++;
        }

        if (nextHash != currentHash)
        {
            //Print total allocs for type and total size
            float reportedBytes = convertToReadableBytes(totalSimiliarSize);
            std::string size = convertToReadableBytesString(totalSimiliarSize);

            char collection_buffer[128];
            sprintf_s(collection_buffer, 128, "\nGroup contained %s allocation(s), Total: %0.3f %s\n", std::to_string(totalSimiliarAllocs).c_str(), reportedBytes, size.c_str());
            printf(collection_buffer);

            //Reset total allocs and size
            totalSimiliarAllocs = 0;
            totalSimiliarSize = 0;
        }

        // Printing a call stack, happens when making report
        char line_buffer[512];
        callstack_line_t lines[128];
        unsigned int line_count = CallstackGetLines(lines, 128, currentNode->current_stack);
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < line_count; ++i)
        {
            // this specific format will make it double click-able in an output window 
            // taking you to the offending line.

            //Print Line For Call Stack
            sprintf_s(line_buffer, 512, "     %s(%u): %s\n", lines[i].file_name, lines[i].line, lines[i].function_name);

            printf(line_buffer);
        }

        currentNode = currentNode->next;
    }
}

void Pop64List(int64_t* arr[], int size)
{
    for (int index = 0; index < size; ++index)
    {
        arr[index] = new int64_t;
        *arr[index] = (int64_t)index;
    }
}

void Pop8List(int8_t* arr[], int size)
{
    for (int index = 0; index < size; ++index)
    {
        arr[index] = new int8_t;
        *arr[index] = (int8_t)index;
    }
}

int main()
{
    if (!CallstackSystemInit())
        return 1;

    const int SIZE_64 = 8000;
    int64_t* arr_64[SIZE_64];
    const int SIZE_8 = 10000;
    int8_t* arr_8[SIZE_8];

    Pop64List(arr_64, SIZE_64);
    Pop8List(arr_8, SIZE_8);

    ReportVerboseCallStacks();

    CallstackSystemDeinit();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, the intent is that the call stack information plus the needed data is `malloc` but the pointer returned is only to the data inside the malloc. the plus one should essentially skip the meta data

Comment: Creating a [mcve] also means to remove everything from your code which is not necessary to reproduce the bug. Often that already helps you to identify the bug yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out the answer. In my reporting function I was using `std::string` to create some of the reporting objects. `std::string` calls `::new` internally to create a small allocation, and then hammers additional memory as the string's internal array reallocates memory. Switching to C-strings solved my problem.